# checking empty string not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm streaming a text file line by line:

```
    TextAsset CardsFileText = Resources.Load("Cards") as TextAsset;
    var Lines = CardsFileText.text.Split("\n"[0]);
```

the first line of the text file is empty:
[image]

But when i want to check in code if line is empty:

```
    foreach (string line in Lines) {
        Debug.Log("NextLIne = " + line);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || line.Equals("") || line.Equals(" ") || line.Equals("\\n") || line.Equals(@"\n"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Equals To None");
        }
    }
```

though in debug i see the String is empty:

[image]

but if statement don't work. ('Equals To None' would not print)
what did i do wrong?

Comment: Try using `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: Use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)` instead of your whole line.

Comment: You probably have a `\r` in your string. I'd suggest using VisualStudio's locals feature to see the contents of the variable because your `Debug.Log` will probably not print any non-printable characters.

Comment: `Split("\n"[0]);` and what in the world you do that? Why you took the first char of your `"\n"` string?

Comment: @SeM wow, didn't notice that at the beginning. Seems like OP does not really know how to do char literals in C#

Answer (score 0):

New line character is spelled "\n", what you have : "\n" means "\"+"n" not newline